# Is it possible to mimic sed's "change line" feature?

Tags: regular-expressions, replace, query-replace-regexp

I'd like to write an elisp function that allows me to replace any line in my buffer matching a regex pattern `<PATTERN>` with text `<TEXT>`. In other words, if line `N` matches `<PATTERN>`, then line `N` is replaced with `<TEXT>`.

For example, if `<PATTERN>` is `^foo` and `<TEXT>` is `bar`, then running the elisp function within the buffer

```
Arcu ante habitasse inceptos congue.
Odio magnis at aenean at est.
foo eget, eu vitae.
Class.
Adipiscing dis donec tellus imperdiet curae.
fooSem sit tristique lacus ut porta accumsan.
Amet ad duis velit sit amet.
```

would change the buffer to

```
Arcu ante habitasse inceptos congue.
Odio magnis at aenean at est.
bar
Class.
Adipiscing dis donec tellus imperdiet curae.
bar
Amet ad duis velit sit amet.
```

This is exactly the behavior of the `sed` command `sed '/^foo/c\bar'`.

Comment: This is nothing more complicated than a regexp replacement with `.*` suffixed to your regexp.  Or `^.*foo.*` for matching anywhere in a line.  Of course you can write a function which searches for only the original pattern and then manipulates the current line each time it finds a match, but my point is that you don't need to do that unless you really want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to…

The answer to this type of question is always yes.

In your case, just run `(replace-regexp "^foo.*$" "bar")`. You can do this interactively with `query-replace-regexp`, which prompts you to verify each match. This helps prevents mistakes. It is bound to `C-M-%` by default.